# Getting a public variable out of a helper into template

Tags: php, magento

Using Magento I have a variable defined in a class something like:

in app/code/local/Me/MyMod/Helper/Data.php

```
class Me_MyMod_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public $theVar = 'I want this';
}
```

then in app/design/frontend/Me/some.phtml view how can I fetch this variable ?

```
Mage::helper('MyMod')->iDontKnowWhatIamDoing;
```

Comment: `$x =new Me_MyMod_Helper_data(); echo $x->theVar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
class Me_MyMod_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public $theVar = 'I want this';

   public function send_to_template() {
      return $this->theVar;
   }
}
```

And in template:

```
Mage::helper('MyMod')->send_to_template();
```

Answer (score 0):

write below function in Data.php

```
class Me_MyMod_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
  public function getThis() 
  {
  $theVar = 'I want this';
  return $theVar;
  }
}
```

call your variable using below code

```
echo Mage::helper('MyMod')->getThis();
```